# Unable to send email from a ec2 instance using postfix

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix

I find that I did not receive email for a while. When I checked the log I see error messages like this:

```
  1 Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtpd[24969]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
  2 Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtpd[24969]: 92963C1550: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
  3 Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/cleanup[24972]: 92963C1550: message-id=<54fa727c90159_61903c7ea44684@ip-179-45-37-216.mail>
  4 Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/qmgr[23814]: 92963C1550: from=<sensu@monitoring.work.com>, size=1398, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  5 Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtpd[24969]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
  6 Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtp[24973]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
  7 Mar  7 03:37:34 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtp[24973]: 92963C1550: to=<anthony@work.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[74.125.28.27]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.09/0/0.17/1.5, dsn    =2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1425699441 md9si17726259pdb.104 - gsmtp)
  8 Mar  7 03:37:34 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/qmgr[23814]: 92963C1550: removed
```

The domain `work.com` is hosted on google gmail. How can I find out what is wrong?

I have not set any outbound rule in the security group used by this aws ec2 instance.

Comment: Gmail has accepted your message. Have you check the spam folder? *to=<anthony@work.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[74.125.28.27]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.09/0/0.17/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, **status=sent***

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I am so fixated on the `Network is unreachable` part of the error log. Please turn your comment to an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: `Network is unreachable` in IPv6 usually means the path from the EC2 to Gmail [still doesn't support IPv6](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=536049)

Comment: @masegaloeh Thanks again! I promptly deleted my last comment because I realised you have addressed it in your answer! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This log has two important lines

```
Mar  7 03:37:32 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtp[24973]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar  7 03:37:34 ip-179-45-37-216 postfix/smtp[24973]: 92963C1550: to=<anthony@work.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[74.125.28.27]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.09/0/0.17/1.5, dsn    =2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1425699441 md9si17726259pdb.104 - gsmtp)
```

*The first line tells us* that your server trying to connect Gmail server through IPv6 but it can't because the IPv6 network in your environment was broken. *The second line tells us* that after the IPv6 failure postfix will fallback to IPv4 mode and send your email via IPv4 address (74.125.28.27).

You can force postfix to disable IPv6 in your postfix via this parameter in `main.cf`

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

References: [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_protocols)